# r ggvis axis format with percentage and decimal places

Tags: r, decimal, axis, percentage, ggvis

I want to ask, if someone knows answer regarding axis format in r package ggvis.
I am using % axis format, but I want to add som decimal places depending on spread of CVaR.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Zu6.png)
Here is my code :

```
Datovka %>% ggvis(x = ~yShort,y = ~xShort,strokeWidth:=1, stroke:="blue",  strokeWidth.hover := 3) %>% layer_paths() %>% layer_paths(x = ~yNoShort, y = ~xNoShort, data = DatovkaNoShort , stroke :="green",strokeWidth:=1, strokeWidth.hover := 3)  %>%
  layer_points(~vol,~r,data = vynosyR, fill := ~isinP, key := ~id , size := 60, size.hover :=120 ) %>%
  # hide_legend("fill") %>%
  add_tooltip(all_values, "hover") %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "CVaR",format = "%" , title_offset = 50) %>%
  add_axis("y", title = "Expected return", format = "%" , title_offset = 50) %>%
  scale_numeric("y", nice = FALSE, clamp = TRUE)  %>%
  scale_numeric("x", nice = FALSE, clamp = TRUE) }
```

Thank you

Comment: When asking for plotting help it's especially useful to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can copy/paste the code to run it and test possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about formating here: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1) / 100, y = runif(10))
df %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% layer_paths() %>% add_axis("x", format = '.2%')
```